# SQL Server : What is a buffer and on cold buffer pool

Tags: sql-server

I [came across this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2009/03/17/sql-server-what-is-a-cold-dirty-or-clean-buffer.aspx).

1. I understand what a Buffer Pool is. But what is a Buffer?
2. Regarding this line (last line in the article):
   "Buffers on the free list that have some age to them may be termed cold because the age increases the chance that they accessible"

his seems counter-intuitive
"Buffers on the free list that have some age to them may be termed cold because the age increases the chance that they accessible"

If you apply the normal LRU caching algorithm, if something is staying for long in the buffer, then it should be the least accessible, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.I understand what a Buffer Pool is. But what is a Buffer?

A buffer is a place in memory that holds pages from a database. It could be anything from index, IAM, data, PFS, etc. These pages are in the buffer pool (hence a pool of buffers via the name) and all have an associated BUF structure that points to the data in memory and holds other metadata about the buffer and data.

> 2.Regarding this line (last line in the article): "Buffers on the free list that have some age to them may be termed cold because the age
>   increases the chance that they accessible"

If a buffer is on the free list, then it's been freed and able to be re-used by something else. It seems like this has to do with the time a buffer is on the free list being proportional to the chance that it could be retrieved form a lower level cache (such as L3 on-die) instead of main memory. If there is a large free list then I doubt this would be the case.